# Ergodic Recurrence

Tags: functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

My solution concerning a problem about Ergodic Recurrence requires me to prove that $\|P_T 1_B\| > 0$.

Where $P_T$ is the projection onto the space $I := \{f \in L^2 : f \circ T = f\}$, $T$ is a measure preserving mapping (so for all $B$ measurable $\mu(T^{-1} B) = \mu(B)$) and $B$ is of positive measure.

Can someone hint my why $\|P_T 1_B\|$ should be strictly positive? If $1_B$ would be in $I$ then I would have that $T^{-1} B = B$ which is probably not the case.

Comment: Can you describe $P_T 1_B$ explicitly?

Comment: @Rasmus: That didn't look too easy, should I try harder?

Comment: I don't know either. I was just bothering. ;)

Comment: I deleted my flawed solution. Maybe it could be repaired, but Theo's is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether $B$ is invariant or not, it only has to be of positive measure, so that its characteristic function $[B]$ is nonzero in $L^{2}$. I assume that $X$ is a finite measure space (so $[X] \in L^{2}$) and that $T: X \to X$ is a measure-preserving transformation.

Clearly, $P_{T}[X] = [X]$, so 
\[
0 < \mu(B) = \langle [B],[X] \rangle = 
\langle [B], P_{T}[X] \rangle = \langle P_{T}[B],[X]\rangle
\]
using $P_{T}^{\ast} = P_{T}$ in the last equation, hence $P_{T}[B] \neq 0$ in $L^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $1\in I$. Hence, if $P_1$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}1$ (i.e., onto the space of constant functions),
$$
\|P_T1_B\|\,\ge\,\|P_11_B\| = \langle 1_B,1\rangle = \int 1_B\,d\mu = \mu(B) > 0.
$$